# Eloquent Create::() method, not accepting numbered keys array for insert

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I use eloquent's Create() method, and try to pass it a numbered array, instead of a key paired array, it actually inserts into DB, but full of null records into the columns. E.G:

```
$v =  [
    0 => "123456789"
    1 => "123456789"
    2 => "123456789"
    3 => "123456789"
];

Model::create($v);
```

It fills that DB table with: `null, null, null, null`

Model has the `$fillable` property well declared, let's say:

```
protected $fillable = [
   'col_name1',
   'col_name2',
   'col_name3',
   'col_name4',
];
```

Looking into to doc, it seems this create method would expect a well paired name => column format. Can anyone confirm?

Is there any way eloquent can address that array position 0 is equal to the first model column/property, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

> Looking into to doc, it seems this create method would expect a `name => column` format.

Not exactly, rather `column_name => value`. You can not pass a numeric array to the `create` method of a model. What you probably could do is get the column listing of the model and then merge that with the values you have. A bit hacky, but should work:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

Model::create(array_combine(Schema::getColumnListing(
    app(Model::class)->getTable()
), $v));
```

Or with only the fillable attributes of the model:

```php
Model::create(array_combine(
    app(Model::class)->getFillable(), 
    $v
));
```

Notes:

- [`Schema::getColumnListing()`](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Schema.html#method_getColumnListing) returns an array of database columns for the model
- The values in `$v` must be in the correct order for this to work
- [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) combines two arrays into an associative array

Comment: Beware that `getColumnListing()` returns *all* table columns including id, created_at/updated_at etc in alphabetical order – which are not supposed to be fillable

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but I suggest you don't do that. In practice `$fillable` prop always changes as your app grows and it's not a good idea to depend on the order of its items.

But if for some reason you need it you can go with `getFillable()` to get the attributes and then combine it with values like so

```
array_combine(
  (new Model)->getFillable(), 
  $v
)
```

which would return

```
[
  'col_name1' => "123456789",
  'col_name2' => "123456789",
  'col_name3' => "123456789",
  'col_name4' => "123456789",
]
```